# Custom iterator for use in `std::sort`

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to create a custom container and iterator.

Here is what I have so far:

```
std::array<int, 1000> global_data;

class TestVectorIterator
{
public:
    TestVectorIterator()
        : index(0)
    {
    }

    TestVectorIterator(int index)
        : index(index)
    {
    }

    int& operator*()
    {
        return global_data[index];
    }

    const int& operator*() const
    {
        return global_data[index];
    }

    TestVectorIterator& operator++()
    {
        index++;
        return *this;
    }

    TestVectorIterator& operator--()
    {
        index--;
        return *this;
    }

    friend int operator- (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.index - rhs.index;
    }

    friend int operator+ (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.index + rhs.index;
    }

    friend bool operator== (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index == rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) == (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator!= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index != rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) != (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator<= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index <= rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) <= (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator>= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index >= rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) >= (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator< (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index < rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) < (*rhs);
    }

    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

private:
    int index = 0;
};

class TestVector
{
public:

    typedef TestVectorIterator iterator;
    typedef const TestVectorIterator const_iterator;

    TestVector()
    {
    }

    int size()
    {
        return global_data.size();
    }

    TestVector::iterator begin()
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(0);
    }

    TestVector::iterator end()
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(size());
    }

    TestVector::const_iterator cbegin()
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(0);
    }

    TestVector::const_iterator cend()
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(size());
    }

    int& operator[](int i)
    {
        return global_data[i];
    }
};
```

It is working fine with range `for` loops, but gives compile time error when used with `std::sort`:

[image]

I haven't used C++ in a while, so I'm guessing I'm missing something simple (or doing something just plain wrong).

**Edit:**

After taking `Holt`'s answer, here is compiling code:

```
std::array<int, 1000> global_data;

class TestVectorIterator
{
public:
    TestVectorIterator()
        : index(0)
    {
    }

    TestVectorIterator(int index)
        : index(index)
    {
    }

    int& operator*()
    {
        return global_data[index];
    }

    const int& operator*() const
    {
        return global_data[index];
    }

    TestVectorIterator& operator++()
    {
        index++;
        return *this;
    }

    TestVectorIterator& operator--()
    {
        index--;
        return *this;
    }

    friend int operator- (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.index - rhs.index;
    }

    friend TestVectorIterator operator-(TestVectorIterator const& lhs, int rhs)
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(lhs.index - rhs);
    }

    friend TestVectorIterator operator+(TestVectorIterator const& lhs, int rhs)
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(lhs.index + rhs);
    }

    friend TestVectorIterator operator+(int lhs, TestVectorIterator const& rhs)
    {
        return TestVectorIterator(lhs + rhs.index);
    }

    friend TestVectorIterator& operator+= (TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        lhs.index += rhs.index;
        return lhs;
    }

    friend TestVectorIterator& operator-= (TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        lhs.index -= rhs.index;
        return lhs;
    }

    friend bool operator== (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index == rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) == (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator!= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index != rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) != (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator<= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index <= rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) <= (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator>= (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index >= rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) >= (*rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator< (const TestVectorIterator& lhs, const TestVectorIterator& rhs)
    {
        if (rhs.index >= global_data.size())
        {
            return lhs.index < rhs.index;
        }

        return (*lhs) < (*rhs);
    }

    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

private:
    int index = 0;
};
```

Comment: `+` snd `-` should take an integer on the right side, not another iterator. Adding iterators makes no more sense than adding pointers.

Comment: For `std::sort`, your iterator must meet the requirements of random access iterator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator As @molbdnilo mentioned, your `+` operator is wrong, but you also need `+=` and `-=`, and "index" operator `[]` (for the iterator, not the test vector).

Comment: @molbdnilo `-` makes sense for iterator, it gives you the distance between two random access iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), your iterators must meet the requirements of [LegacyRandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which implies [LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) and [LegacyIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator).

Your `TestVectorIterator` is lacking a bunch of overloads to meet such requirements. In particular:

- `operator+(TestVectorIterator const&, TestVectorIterator const&)` makes no sense, you need `operator+(TestVectorIterator const&, int)` and `operator+(int, TestVectorIterator const&)`;
- you need `TestVectorIterator operator-(TestVectorIterator const&, int)`;
- you need compound operators: `+=`, `-=`;
- you need postfix increment and decrement `TestVectorIterator operator++(int)` and `TestVectorIterator operator--(int)`;
- you need a subscript operator `int& operator[](int)`.